# How to provide extra methods for returning IHttpActionResult?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ApiController that returns `OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>` with a resource collection, paginated. Naturally, there will be more methods that return paginated collections.

The `content` in the result of all those actions looks roughly like this:

- A `Data` property with the current items
- A `PagingMeta` property with paging metadata such as total pages and total items
- A `PagingLinks` property that contain links to first/prev/next/last pages

My backend returns a custom `PagedList<T>` object and I have another `PagedListResponse<T>` that contains the above properties. It's a simple transformation from one to the other.

Now, in Web API, the `ApiController` provides a couple of convenient methods for returning `IHttpActionResult`, such as:

- `Ok<T>(T value)`
- `Content<T>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value)`

I was hoping to make it just as easy for the controller to return a paged result just as easily.

For the moment I have an extension method that provides it, with the following signature:

```
public static OkNegotiatedContentResult<PagedListResult<T>> OkPaged<T>(this ApiController controller, /* other parameters */)
```

The "ugly" is that you can only call an extension method by including the `this` keyword:

```
return this.OkPaged(myResult);
```

the only other option I can see is to implement a base controller class, but I generally try to avoid such inheritance structures because they tend to get troublesome later down the road.

What does ASP.NET provide in terms of extension points to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a class that inherits from IHttpActionResult and use that as your return value, e.g

```
public class HttpStatusCodeResultWithContent<T> : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage;

    private readonly HttpStatusCode statusCode;

    public HttpStatusCodeResultWithContent(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T model)
    {
        this.httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessage;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        ResponseModel = model;
    }

    public T ResponseModel { get; private set; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(statusCode, ResponseModel);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

That gives you an easily testable class in HttpStatusCodeResultWithContent, that allows you to return any content with any HTTP Status Code.

Then from your controller code,

```
var pagedListResult = someObject.GetPagedList();
return new HttpStatusCodeResultWithContent<PagedListResult<T>(Request, HttpStatusCode.OK, pagedListResult);
```

You can then use extension methods if you like on ApiController to wrap up access to this - that's pretty much all that's going on inside ApiController, e.g. here's what the 'Ok' method on ApiController looks like.

```
protected internal virtual OkNegotiatedContentResult<T> Ok<T>(T content)
{
    return new OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>(content, this);
}
```